# リストの後にコードサンプルを表示しても整形されない

Tags: サポート, 仕様, markdown

リスト要素の直後にスペース4つでインデントしてもソースコードが整形されないですが、仕様でしょうか？

---

1. あ
2. い
3. う

   print("hello world") // 整形されない

   - li要素の中にp要素が追加されているようです。

```
//htmlタグを直接書いて、pre要素を使えば回避可能
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Markdown の仕様です。

   リスト項目の中に複数の段落を入れられるように、リスト項目に続く4文字インデントはリスト項目の一部として扱われます。
2. もちろんSEメタでも話題にはなっていて、 `<!-- -->` とか適当なもので区切ってくれ、とのこと。

   [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99637/286934)

```
ここはリストの外のコードブロック
```

3. （これはリストが続いているわけではなく、3から始めた新しいリストです）
4. リスト要素の中にコードブロックを書きたい場合：さらに4文字インデントします。

   [Daring Fireball: Markdown Syntax Documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list)

   ```
   ここはリストの中のコードブロック
   ```

---

```
1.  Markdown の仕様です。

    リスト項目の中に複数の段落を入れられるように、リスト項目に続く4文字インデントはリスト項目の一部として扱われます。

2.  もちろんSEメタでも話題にはなっていて、 `<!-- -->` とか適当なもので区切ってくれ、とのこと。

    [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item][1]

<!-- -->

    ここはリストの外のコードブロック

3.  （これはリストが続いているわけではなく、3から始めた新しいリストです）

4.  リスト要素の中にコードブロックを書きたい場合：さらに4文字インデントします。

    [Daring Fireball: Markdown Syntax Documentation][2]

        ここはリストの中のコードブロック
```